# What is the password for Windows 10 Sandbox Administrator?

Tags: windows, windows-sandbox

Given a Windows 10 Sandbox instance, I want to run an Application as the local Administrator.

In a powershell console within a Sandbox instance, I tried using `runas.exe`:

```
PS > runas.exe /user:Administrator C:\Windows\System32\whoami.exe
Enter the password for Administrator:
Attempting to start whoami.exe as user "9880B335-37DC-4\Administrator" ...
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - C:\Windows\System32\whoami.exe
1326: The user name or password is incorrect.
```

What is the password for `Administrator` in a Windows Sandbox instance?

Comment: On my machine, the Sandbox admin password if needed would be the same as the host machine account admin password. I do not recall actually needing it except for normal apps needing to OK UAC.

Comment: Have you tried the existing local admin account pwd? MS using a default local admin password makes very little sense at all. Using a password you were prompted to create, or more likely, the existing local admin pwd, is more likely.

Comment: "What is the password for Administrator in a Windows Sandbox instance?" - Whatever the password to the Administrator account on your machine.  Since it's your machine we can't provide an answer to this question.  The Administrator account by default is disabled.  You might try changing the password using a different user account.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the suggestions. The password is blank! See the Answer below.

Answer (score 1):

*tl;dr* the Windows Sandbox *Administrator* must be enabled and blank passwords allowed. The password is blank.

### Enable *Administrator*

By default, the Windows Sandbox *Administrator* account is disabled.

```
PS > Get-LocalUser -Name "Administrator"

Name          Enabled Description
----          ------- -----------
Administrator False   Built-in account for administering the computer/domain
```

To enable the *Administrator* account

```
net user "Administrator" /active:yes
```

### Allow blank passwords

Then set policy `Accounts: Limit local account use of blank passwords to console logon only` to *Disabled*.

1. Start `gpedit.msc`
2. Browse to *Computer Configuration* > *Windows Settings* > *Security Settings* > *Local Policies* > *Security Options*
3. Open `Accounts: Limit local account use of blank passwords to console logon only`
4. Select *Disabled*
5. click *Apply* and *OK*

[image]

### `runas Administrator` using blank password

To test, start an elevated `cmd.exe` command using `runas.exe`. Use a blank password (just press <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

```
PS > runas.exe /user:Administrator C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
Enter the password for Administrator:
Attempting to start C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe as user "3C3F3100-C191-4\Administrator" ...
```

In the new `cmd.exe` window, check the user

```
C:\Windows\system32>whoami.exe
3c3f3100-c191-4\administrator
```